# How to avoid removing all Docker containers and images while developing a containeraized Python application

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I'm developing a Python application for Machine Learning models, you can see my docker-compose file here: https://github.com/Quilograma/IES_Project/blob/main/docker-compose.yml.

The problem is while developing the application, every time I change a line in the Python code I've to kill all active containers and drop their respective images. Then call docker-compose up to see the change I've made. It takes roughly 5 minutes to pull all Docker images and install the Python libraries again, which significantly slows down the process of development.

Is there any turnaround to overcome this issue? I really want to use the containers. Thanks!

Comment: Can you do day-to-day development in a non-Docker virtual environment?  It could make sense to run dependencies like databases in containers, but otherwise do most of your development on the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to remove any images. You need to re-build **your** image. This means all previous image layers (`FROM python:<tag>`, `RUN pip install <packages...>`) would be **cached**.

The alternative solution (but only because Python in an interpreted language) would be to mount your module as a volume. Then when you save in your host filesystem, it is automatically updated inside the container.

[Personal example with Flask server](https://github.com/OneCricketeer/kelda-examples/blob/master/flask-kafka-elastic/docker-compose/docker-compose.yml#L20-L21) and Kafka connection

Comment: Indeed, i do not need to build all images, just the Python ones. 
Could you please provide a link for such a sample code for how to bind Python module as volume a run it? Thanks.

Comment: My answer already has a link

Comment: Even if you add a library, you never need to remove any image. You only would re-build. Or, if you are running a long-running web server like Flask as my example, then never modify the `app`, and only external imported modules like in a model-view-controller pattern, then you'd simply refresh the web browser, and it'll execute the new Python code without rebuilding. Just like it would without Docker

Comment: Or another example, `docker run --rm -v ./app.py:/workdir/app.py python:3 /workdir/app.py`... I can run that as many times as needed, and I don't need to build or re-pull any image more than once